# ORM query builder for complex condition in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.3, selectquerybuilder

I have `user_messages` table with columns `id, sender_id, receiver_id, message, deleted`

I have to retrieve all messages like this

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    user_messages UserMessages 
WHERE (
    UserMessages.deleted = false
    AND (
        (sender_id = $loggedin_user_id AND receiver_id = $user_id)
        OR 
        (sender_id = $user_id AND receiver_id = $loggedin_user_id)
    ) 
ORDER BY 
    created DESC
```

Currently, I'm using this query builder

```
$message_by_list = $this->UserMessages->find()
    ->where(['UserMessages.deleted' => false])
    ->andWhere(function ($exp) {
        return $exp->or_([
            'sender_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
            'receiver_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
        ]);
    })
```

which is generating sql query as

```
FROM 
    user_messages UserMessages  
WHERE 
    (UserMessages.deleted = false AND (sender_id = $loggedin_user_id OR receiver_id = $loggedin_user_id)) 
ORDER BY 
    created DESC
```

How to write optimized ORM Query to retrieve data as above?

> Edit 2 : Updated query for arilia's answer

```
WHERE (
        (
            UserMessages.deleted = false
        ) 
        AND 
        (
            (
                UserMessages.sender_id = $loggedin_user_id
                AND 
                UserMessages.receiver_id = $user_id
            )
            OR 
            UserMessages.sender_id = $user_id 
            OR                         /// doubt here
            UserMessages.receiver_id = $loggedin_user_id
        )
    )
```

Comment: is edit2 the query you want to obtain or the query generated by my code? Because I get an AND where you put 'doubt here', not an OR

Comment: That is the query generated by your code

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$message_by_list = $this->UserMessages->find()
    ->where(['sender_id' => $user_id, 'receiver_id' => $logged_user_id])
    ->orWhere(['sender_id' => $logged_user_id, 'receiver_id' => $user_id])
    ->andWhere(['UserMessages.deleted' => false]);
```

Comment: I have a doubt in generated query. Check check for `/// doubt here` in updated code. I think it will fetch records matching only one column